# What is better to use keras.preprocessing.tokenizer or nltk.tokenize

Tags: python, keras, nltk, tokenize

I'm working on multiclass classification problem with Keras.
Tried to use Keras tokenize but think that nltk.tokenizer would be better solution for my problem. I did't find any article witch can describe difference in those two tokenizers, what is difference and accuracy of text preprocessing between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default they both use some regular expression based tokenisation. The difference lies in their complexity:

- [Keras Tokenizer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/6ff9af6971f97f69c39d090be15c2f7d93aa4d6d/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L26) just replaces certain punctuation characters and splits on the remaining space character.
- [NLTK Tokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/treebank.html) uses 
  the Treebank tokenizer uses regular expressions to tokenize text as in Penn Treebank.
  This implementation is a port of the tokenizer sed script written by Robert McIntyre
  and available at http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/tokenizer.sed.

They are both very fast since they just run regular expressions. If you have very basic text with not too much punctuation or out of order characters then Keras might be the simplest choice.

If you actually want a neural network based one that can parse numbers, dates etc correctly and potentially perform part-of-speech tagging, entity recognition you can use:

- [Stanford CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) that gives a full pipeline for processing text, finding dependencies, recognising entitites etc.
- [SpaCy](https://spacy.io/) is also a full Python NLP pipeline that gives you similar results as well a loading corresponding word vectors such as GloVe.

The above two are slower than any regular expression based methods but it depends on the source text you want to process.